# CSS: Background Image for Menu Link isn't Visible in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background

The website I'm working on has a menu that includes a logo image as a background for the last link. For some reason that image doesn't appear in IE, even though it shows up fine in all other browsers.

Here's the site:

http://www.cybart.com/bscg/

I would appreciate it if someone could take a look at my CSS and suggest the Internet Explorer version:

```
 #access {
    left:70%;
    top:140px;
    margin-left:-600px;
        width: 280px;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    float:left;"
    }

#access ul {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
}

#access ul,
#access ul ul {
list-style-type:none;
width: 250px;
}

#access ul ul {
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display:none;
}


#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}


#access ul li:last-child {
height:77px;
background: url(images/aba/ABALinkRed.jpg) no-repeat top left;
text-indent: -3000px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
}

#access ul li:last-child a {
background:transparent;
height:77px;
}

#access ul ul li:last-child {
background:transparent;
height:32px;
text-indent: 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}

#access ul ul li:last-child a {
background:#fff;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
height:18px;
}


#access ul a,
#access ul ul a {
display:block;
padding: 7px 0 7px 10px;
background:#fff;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
text-decoration:none;
color:black;

} 


#access ul ul {
padding-left:40px;
margin-left:-20px;
}

#access ul ul a {
margin-left: -20px;
padding-left:20px;
width:230px;
}


#access ul a:hover,
#access ul ul a:hover {
color: #CA0000;
}

#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
color: #CA0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in IE9, so I assume you're using IE8.

This is how you're adding the image:

```
#access ul li:last-child {
    background: url(images/aba/ABALinkRed.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

The reason it doesn't work is that `:last-child` is not supported in IE until version 9, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudoclasses

Comment: Thank you, ThirtyDot. Let's say I assign the .aba_logo class to the link in question. Could you please show me how to make it work?

Comment: Then instead of the `#access ul ul li:last-child` declaration, you use `.aba_logo` declaration.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. The background image doesn't appear the way it should when I do that. Could you please take a look at the updated site?

Comment: @Dimitri Vorontzov: The version of the site that's live at the moment is still using `#access ul li:last-child`. Change that to `.aba_logo`.

Comment: I did that a minute ago, could you please take another look? I only see the bottom of the image, and it's not clickable.

Comment: @Dimitri Vorontzov: You haven't uploaded it right or something. The live version is *still* using `#access ul li:last-child`.

Comment: Do you see the image, ThirtyDot? Here's the link to my css:http://cybart.com/bscg/wp-content/themes/BlackSwan/styleie.css that shows the changed declaration.

Comment: I thought you were changing `#access ul li:last-child`. I didn't know you were adding `.aba_logo` to an IE only stylesheet... Yes, I can now see what you're seeing when I check it in IE8. You can only see half the image because you need to make an IE8 version for this: `#access ul li:last-child a {
background:transparent;
height:77px;
}`. So, `.aba_logo a { background:transparent; height:77px; }`. It's highly pointless to have *both* the `:last-child` version and the `.aba_logo` version. You should just replace the `:last-child` version, because right now you have two things to maintain..

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you ThirtyDot - and Shawn Steward - you helped me to fix this! Much appreciated.